# Bluetooth mouse device unsteady pointing

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I've been using this iBall Blueooth FreeGo mouse for a month now. Today i started to give unsteady pointing. This leads to wrong clicks and i'm unable to precisely point objects on my screen

even if i let the mouse stay on any surface, the mouse pointer jerks every second as if i'm moving it

The laptop's in-built mouse-pointer works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can think of, is the following:

- Make sure the batteries are full.
- Check that there is no dust on the sensor area, under the mouse.
- Try the mouse on a difference surface and see if you have the same behavior. (*Edit: Ok, you tried that one already*)

If you still have the problem, then it is possible that your mouse is simply faulty, and I would recommend you contact their support to exchange it. Apparently they offer a 3 years warranty.

Comment: Contacting them would be the best choice because i didn't use it too much to drain batteries that soon